# save bitmap in list for undo c# fails at second time

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a little bit code that allows me (windows form) to load a image, draw a rectangle on it and save it. Yet I want to realise a "Undo" function. If I write a rectangle I draw into the bitmap and save the modified bitmap. After I draw another rectangle I save the bitmap too (in a List). Yet I created a button that deletes the last bitmap I saved and set the bitmap (the new last) as Image in the pictureBox. That works, but If I do another rectangle and click Undo, nothing happens. I am confused and have no Idea, where the problem is. Here my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RecAngle
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    Rectangle mRect;
    Bitmap bm;
    Image file;
    Boolean opened = false;
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    Boolean draw = false;
    List<Bitmap> bitMapList = new List<Bitmap>();
    Boolean undo = false;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mRect = new Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate(); 
            draw = true;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
            bm = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = bm;
            bitMapList.Add(bm);
            opened = true;
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = sfd.ShowDialog();
        if (opened)
        {
                try
                {
                    bm.Save(sfd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (draw)
            {
                if (undo)
                {
                    bm = bitMapList[bitMapList.Count - 1];

                }

                    using (Graphics a = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                    {
                        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
                        a.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
                        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                        bitMapList.Add( new Bitmap(bm));
                        pictureBox1.Image = bitMapList[bitMapList.Count - 1];

                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (bitMapList.Count != 0)
        {
            bitMapList.RemoveAt(bitMapList.Count - 1);
            pictureBox1.Image = bitMapList[bitMapList.Count - 1];
            undo = true;

        }
    }

}
}
```

Do I save something wrong? I think it is something with the "Remove" but I really dont see the error. 
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very confusing. Why are you calling `Invalidate` all the time? Why are you using `List` where `Stack` would be more appropriate? Why are you assigning `bm` when doing undo in the `MouseUp` method, rather then directly in the Undo button click? Why are you keeping the `Graphics` instance alive for so long, when you only need it to paint one rectangle?

And finally, why aren't you setting `undo` back to false?

Also, you're very confused about where what bitmap is at a time. In the Undo method, you're checking `bitMapList.Count != 0`, and then you remove the last item. However, if `bitMapList.Count` is `1`, the next line will cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

You have to break through this confusion. Think about what you're trying to do, and think about how to do it cleanly. This is a mess. What bitmaps do you want in the history? Do you really need a separate bitmap instance for the "actual" bitmap, even though you've just put the very same bitmap in the history? Why aren't you simply treating the latest bitmap in the history as the "current" one? Then you'd simply `Pop` the last item from stack and everything would work with no issue, and cleanly. Of course, you'd have to do the painting on a new instance of the bitmap, but that's no overhead, since `new Bitmap(bm);` does exactly the same thing anyway. The only thing that would change would be the order - you'd create the new bitmap, paint the rectangle and `Push` it to the stack. As simple as that.

Code should be easy to understand. That's one of the primary goals for code maintenance. That's why you want to separate your logic into different methods etc., it has to be easy to read and understand, and having everything in a few methods with small areas of responsibility helps. If you're already in a confusing mess with a code this short, imagine how hard it's going to be to maintain an application that's more complicated than this.

All that said, the quick fix for your immediate issue is changing the undo code in `pictureBox1_MouseUp` like so:

```
if (undo)
{
  bm = new Bitmap(bitMapList[bitMapList.Count - 1]);
  undo = false;
}
```

However, I strongly encourage you to rewrite the code instead, and make it more clear. You're not even naming your controls, that doesn't help readability at all. Why not have `btnUndo` instead of `button3`?

Comment: Thank you for that detailed help! I come from development of webdynpros ABAP and that in a special way. Yet I have to do this "paint" for editing screenshots for a ticketsystem and have to develop the solution quickly but I am absoluetly new to C# and have to make other projects at the same time so that this short code confusing me a lot because every hour I have to change from Webdynpro to Javascript, then to C# an so on...  That problem is fixed yet but I restructure the code and do it with stacks. Really, really thank you for that answer, its great!